# How to print timezone in order confirmation email template

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, timezone

I am trying to print the store timezone in order confirmation email. In my email template, I have added the order date as follows,

```
<div >{{trans ' Order Placed on <span >%created_at</span>' created_at=$order.getCreatedAtFormatted(2) |raw}}</div>
```

I have set the time zone for the store as

[image]

But in my order confirmation email, I am not able to see the time zone with the date. It just shows as,

**Placed on Dec 26, 2019, 3:40:30 PM.**

I would like to add he timezone after the time in order confirmation email. 
Anyone know how to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

Most easy way... change the template code to `created_at=$order.getCreatedAtFormatted(1) |raw`